# how to use row col notation for conditional_format() in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to do some formatting for cells in excel pro-grammatically, based on how many rows of data is filled in excel, I'm using row index to define range of cells.

Please find below code for reference:

```
# Write a conditional format over a range.
    target_sheet.conditional_format([row - len(line),1,row-1,2 ], {'type': 'cell',
                                         'criteria': '>=',
                                         'value': 10,
                                         'format': format1})
```

But this results in following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py", line 80, in cell_wrapper
    int(args[0])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

I'm not sure on how to proceed with this approach, any help is highly appreciated. TIA!

Comment: Just leave out the list brackets. The `conditional_format()` method takes 4 row/col values not a list. It also takes an optional string range but that isn't useful in your case since you are setting the range dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

As [documentation](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html) says, conditional formatting is a feature of Excel which allows you to apply a format to a cell or a range of cells based on certain criteria.

It takes as input a range of cells and the relative format criteria that you would apply to them.
So for example you can do something like this:

```
worksheet.conditional_format('B3:K12', {'type': 'cell',
                                        'criteria': '>=',
                                        'value': 10,
                                        'format': format1})
```

Your code returns this error because you put as first argument a list, but you should use a string like the example above.
You can check additional examples [here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_conditional_format.html#ex-cond-format).

Comment: Yeah @Giordano I see that, but the problem comes when data is dumped dynamically using a program and number of rows changes according to that. Do you have any idea on how this string can be derived programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

The xl_rowcol_to_cell() came to rescue

Please find code below:

```
str1_val = xl_rowcol_to_cell(row-len(line), 1, row_abs=True, col_abs=True)
str2_val = xl_rowcol_to_cell(row-1, 2, row_abs=True, col_abs=True)

    # Write a conditional format over a range.
    target_sheet.conditional_format('%s:%s' % (str1_val, str2_val), {'type': 'cell',
                                         'criteria': '>=',
                                         'value': 10,
                                         'format': format1})

# Write another conditional format over the same range.
    target_sheet.conditional_format('%s:%s' % (str1_val, str2_val), {'type': 'cell',
                                         'criteria': '<',
                                         'value': -0.1,
                                         'format': format2})
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the excellent xlsxwriter documentation on conditional formating only shows  examples with the A1 notation, like:

```
worksheet.conditional_format('B1:B15', {'type': 'bottom', 'value': 10, 'criteria': '%', 'format':   format_red})
```

However row column notation is also possible:

```
worksheet.conditional_format(1,2,15,2, {'type': 'top', 'value': 50, 'criteria': '%', 'format':   format_green}) 
# rowstart, colstart, rowend, colend
```

Result in Excel:
[image]

As per "[Working with Cell Notation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html)":
In general when using the XlsxWriter module you can use A1 notation anywhere you can use row-column notation. This also applies to methods that take a range of cells:

```
worksheet.merge_range(2, 1, 3, 3, 'Merged Cells', merge_format)
worksheet.merge_range('B3:D4',    'Merged Cells', merge_format)
```